# Trouble installing npm

Tags: macos, node.js, coffeescript, npm

I got a clean install on my mac book pro with mountain lion. Then have installed nodejs with homebrew i.e. `brew install nodejs`, but now I cant get npm to install. eg.

```
    $ node -v
    v0.8.6
    $ curl -k https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7882  100  7882    0     0  11359      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 13803
```

Then nothing else happens. NPM is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew does not currently install NPM with Node, per https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/6925f69e/Library/Formula/node.rb#L25-26:

```ruby
def install
  # Why skip npm install? Read https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/8784.
  args = ["--prefix=#{prefix}", "--without-npm"]

  ...

  system "./configure", *args
  system "make install"
end
```

As promised by the formula, you can read more details at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/8784, and a [recent pull request](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/13053) (last updated just 9 hours ago), has even more discussion.

I personally prefer installing from source using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/) instead of Homebrew; the first half of my [Node.js First Steps](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/2-nodejs-first-steps) details installing Node via this method.

It's worth noting that, starting in Node v0.8.6, you can download precompiled binaries for some distributions, including OS X. Just click [the download link](http://nodejs.org/#download) at the http://nodejs.org  and then click ["Other release files"](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.6/); from there, you can download the Darwin 32- or 64-bit binaries and extract them into someplace on your `PATH`.

Comment: It looks like npm was re-entered to the nodejs formula.

Answer (score 2):

Try it without `sudo`:

```
$ curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

The main point of `brew` is that it installs things where you don't need root-level access, and npm's installer is designed to follow the Node installation's lead.

Comment: This gives me a error. Any notions?

`$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
...
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token newline'
sh: line 1: <html>Moved: <a href="https://npmjs.org/install.sh">https://npmjs.org/install.sh</a>'`

Comment: The explanation is right there in the error message: npm now requires you to install is over HTTPS. So: `curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

Comment: It's not as crystal clear as you make it sound, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Press enter, and then you see this:

```
Sorry, try again.
Password:
```

put your password and work.

```
npm@1.1.71 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
It worked
```